# Require for Flux on WebStorm is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, aframe, flux

I'm stack in this problem for a long time. When I try to require Flux on my WebStorm project I get this error for this line of code for file `FluxDispatcher.js`:

```
var Dispatcher = require("flux").Dispatcher;
```

And for this line for file `FluxStore.js`:

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
```

[image]

I've a project made in JavaScript, Aframe and HTML.

Since my project is scaling very quickly, I've to use Flux to handle it better. I cannot use Redux, I need Flux (it's not a choice of mine).

I think that the problem is really simple but I cannot find a solution to this. The project works well without flux, I only need it to handle the state.

Maybe you can think that there is something wrong inside the node directory.
I give you the repo: https://github.com/PietroMeloni/FluxOnAframe (I made a new one now, of course in the Flux implementation there are errors since I cannot debug when I have an error on first lines).

I admit that I'm pretty ignorant in facts of Node, so if you think that my question is stupid I apologize for that.

Update 1:
Reading the documentation lead me to modify my code in this way:

```
var requirejs = require(['requirejs'], function(requirejs) {
    requirejs.config
    ({       
        nodeRequire: require
    });
    Dispatcher = requirejs("flux").Dispatcher;
    AppDispatcher = new Dispatcher();
});
```

But I get this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 63342/TopBar/requirejs.js:1

I edited my code like that because i followed the documentation [in requirejs node documentation](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#3) then, since i got this:
"Uncaught Error: Module name "requirejs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])", I had to edit my code following this on the official documentation:
[in requirejs not loaded documentation](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded)

Comment: Please see https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded. But in your case it seems that you are trying to load commonjs modules via requirejs - this won't work without conversion. See https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't solved my problem. Reading documentation lead me to edit my code. I modified my question so maybe it easier for anyone to read it better.